# Why I get First-chance exception if no one calls the function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, exception, first-chance-exception

Suddenly my code started to throws an exception `First-chance exception at 0x7731c41f in VideoPlayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: GenICam::RuntimeException at memory location 0x0018f5dc..` I could not find where exactly it throws from, so I commented all in `main` function and everything outside the `main`. I started to uncomment blocks of code one by one whilst the code in `main` remains **commented**. While doing it I noticed that there is function `A` that when it is commented there is no exception, but when it's uncommented it throws the exception above.

I don't understand how it can cause exeception if it's not called ( I placed breakpoint in it and code in main is commented)?

Comment: have you change any project property ??

Comment: @IAMHERE, no I have not.

Answer (score 2):

You function will be used during the static initialization.
Take the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
bool static_func()
{
    std::cout << "Before main" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
static const bool b = static_func();
int main()
{
    std::cout << "We are main" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since you only see a first chance exception it will be caught and handled. I have seen such constructs in abstract factories for example, where the factory configures itself.
The reason why your breakpoint is not hit must be something else.

Comment: I checked the code in `A` function and there is use of 3rd-party type (`BCamera camera;`). Probably when `A` is commented linker exclude it from final code and when `A` is uncommented linker include that type and because of that probably somewhere there are some global/static objects instantiation. Is there any way to debug such thing?

Answer (score 0):

In VS, Debug menu, Exceptions... check the throw column for the matching type. Then start debugging and it will stop exactly where throw happens. And you can look around why.